# Can I inject a service into a directive in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to inject a service into a directive like below:

```
 var app = angular.module('app',[]);
 app.factory('myData', function(){
     return {
        name : "myName"
     }
 });
 app.directive('changeIt',function($compile, myData){
    return {
            restrict: 'C',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.name = myData.name;
            }
        }
 });
```

But this is returning me an error `Unknown provider: myDataProvider`. Could someone please look into the code and tell me if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 391, accepted):

You can do injection on Directives, and it looks just like it does everywhere else.

```
app.directive('changeIt', ['myData', function(myData){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.name = myData.name;
        }
    }
 }]);
```

Comment: I think this is a better solution because it works even after minifying your code.

Comment: I had to add '_myData = myData' prior to the return {} and then reference the object as _myData inside of the link function.

Comment: Thanks @Jelling.  I had to do the same thing.  I wonder if anyone out there could tell us why...?

Comment: because closure. http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: any particular reason to inject $compile in the directive? it doesn't seem to be used anywhere.

Comment: Is there a solution to injecting if you want to create the link function outside of the directive call?

Comment: Can you inject multiple services?

Answer (score 19):

Change your directive definition from `app.module` to `app.directive`. Apart from that everything looks fine. 

<strike>Btw, very rarely do you have to inject a service into a directive. If you are injecting a service ( which usually is a data source or model ) into your directive ( which is kind of part of a view ), you are creating a direct coupling between your view and model. You need to separate them out by wiring them together using a controller.</strike>

It does work fine. I am not sure what you are doing which is wrong. Here is a plunk of it working.

http://plnkr.co/edit/M8omDEjvPvBtrBHM84Am

Comment: Can you provide an example please

Comment: @Exception Can you put your code in a fiddle? I can have a look and see why your code isnt working and probably help you fix it.

Comment: @Exception added a working plunk that shows the code working.

Comment: I just discovered something: If you define an injection in the function parameters, `function($location) { ...` but do not actually refer to `$location` inside the function, AngularJS will not perform the injection. The only time you'd ever notice this behavior is inside the debugger.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with your "coupled" comment. We already couple the controller and service globally - we cannot programaticaly replace the service's implementation at runtime. Which means a single controller gets a single service. However - directives have isolated configuration per tag on the page, so potentially we enable different service to different directive instances. Seems to me this is less decoupled.

Comment: As an example of where I use a factory and directives: Using Google APIs often gives me an instance of that API as a Javascript object. A service can hold that particulate instance so you do not have to instantiate multiple objects every time you need to use it. Also, using a provider can embed the loading of the API. You can then in your Angular .run method call the privider initialization which loads the API and saves the instance for others to use.

Comment: What would you suggest as an alternative? Using an outer-controller? I think I'm leaning towards agreeing with guy - especially when you think about writing components: https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/component-based-angularjs-directives

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the $inject service to get whatever service you like. I find that useful if I don't know the service name ahead of time but know the service interface. For example a directive that will  plug a table into an ngResource end point or a generic delete-record button which interacts with any api end point. You don't want to re-implement the table directive for every controller or data-source.

`template.html`

```
<div my-directive api-service='ServiceName'></div>
```

`my-directive.directive.coffee`

```
angular.module 'my.module'
  .factory 'myDirective', ($injector) ->
    directive = 
      restrict: 'A'
      link: (scope, element, attributes) ->
        scope.apiService = $injector.get(attributes.apiService)
```

now your 'anonymous' service is fully available. If it is ngResource for example you can then use the standard ngResource interface to get your data

For example:

```
scope.apiService.query((response) ->
  scope.data = response
, (errorResponse) ->
  console.log "ERROR fetching data for service: #{attributes.apiService}"
  console.log errorResponse.data
)
```

I have found this technique to be very useful when making elements that interact with API endpoints especially.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using directive as a separate module need to import service like below

```
    app.module('ChangeItDirective',['myData'])
     .directive('changeIt', ['myData', function(myData){
       return {
         restrict: 'C',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.name = myData.name;
         }
        }
     }]);
```

Otherwise it will be like below

```
    app.directive('changeIt', ['myData', function(myData){
       return {
         restrict: 'C',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.name = myData.name;
         }
        }
     }]);
```