# Creating an angular directive that binds a service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, restangular

Not sure if I am misunderstanding how directives are created here. Say for example I have a controller such as:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'MyService', function($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.restangularService = MyService;
}
```

I then have a directive such as:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives').directive('myGrid', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'some/path/here.html',
        scope: {
            restangularService: '&'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            //access $scope.restangularService to run some queries
        }
    };
});
```

I then use my directive as such:

```
<div data-my-grid data-restangular-service='restangularService'></div>
```

I would expect that in my directive I could access `$scope.restangularService` and make calls however it's not being populated correctly. Am I doing this totally wrong? Any input? I have a feeling I need to be using the ngModel directive somehow.

Comment: Consider injecting the service into the directive instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569168/injecting-service-to-directive

Comment: @marck That is what I was doing however I would like to be able to pass the service in as a parameter so I don't have to have a directive for each service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "&" prefix of an isolate scope value in a directive provides "one-way binding" which makes available a getter function in the directive's scope.

Any changes you make to the object will not make their way back up to the parent controller of the directive (it is "read-only"). So you can't access your 'restangularService' variable as you would in the controller's scope, without calling the getter function:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).directive('myGrid', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'some/path/here.html',
        scope: {
            restangularService: '&'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            console.log($scope.restangularService()); // outputs service value
        }]
    };
})
```

Alternatively, you could use "=", which would allow you directly access the scope object you pass in:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).directive('myGrid', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'some/path/here.html',
        scope: {
            restangularService: '='
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            console.log($scope.restangularService); //outputs service value
        }]
    };
})
```

[Plunk demonstrating both types](http://plnkr.co/edit/cjKTsFLLHcuaf5SyI01Q)

Comment: & is for binding a function. @ is for on-way binding.