# angularjs app design multiple instances of the same component (directive or directive+controller)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

My app needs to have multiple instances of a component that manages a complex model.

to display the model and the UI/DOM logic including a template with child directives I'v created a directive,

the thing is for each of this model/directives I also needs some business logic like manipulating the model/retrieving additional data from the server, etc.. and I do not feel right to have this is inside the directive.

An example could be an app that displays 10 visible todo lists on screen.

my question is if its a good idea to have a controller instance on each of the components in a way that the directive and the controller are initiated from the same element and share the same scope to mange a single model? something that may look look like this:

```
<div class="todo-ui-directive" ng-repeat="todoList in lists" ng-controller="todoCtrl">
</div>
```

Comment: mark answer por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want to use services to share business logic like that.
You can use dependency injection in your directive to achieve this: [Injecting service to Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569168/injecting-service-to-directive)

Directives also can create controllers to share between instances. There's a good chance the solution you're looking for is a combination of both. 
http://jasonmore.net/angular-js-directives-difference-controller-link/

Comment: Thank you,
I do not necessarily mean retrieving the data using a controller but more like invoking the request from the controller, of course the retrieval itself will happen using a service. the main idea was I need somewhere to place my business logic..

Comment: I sounds like a directive controller might be what you're looking for

Comment: regarding directive's controllers, I am somewhat confused.
My understanding so far was this feature is used to expose an API for other directives without exposing the scope.
this is not really what I need here