# Adding html in a directive that contains directives

Tags: angularjs

HTML

```
<div show-orders ng-click="showOrderDetails()" ></div>
```

Javascript

```
var ddApp = angular.module('ddApp', []);

ddApp.directive('showOrders', [function ($compile)
{
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs)
    {
      scope.showOrderDetails = function ()
      {
        // How I would normally insert HTML.
        element.append('<div order-details>Some text</div>');

        // How do you use $compile here???
        //el = $compile(tpl)(scope);
      }
    }
  };
} ]);

ddApp.directive('orderDetails', [function ()
{
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs)
    {
      // Do something
    }
  };
} ]);
```

When you click on the div, the showOrderDetails gets called. I then want to append some html to the div (i.e., insert it into the div). However, the html that I am inserting is a div containing another directive called order-details. How do I compile this html and insert it into the div so that Angular is aware of the order-details directive?

Another question. I'm not sure if placing the html code directly within the click event is the right solution. What if I wanted to have this come from some template, so that I could reuse the template elsewhere. Is it possible to load the html from a service or factory? If so, how? Is this the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15573493/753632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var template='<div order-details>Some text</div>'
element.append($compile(template)(scope));
```

yes it possible to load template using services

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/views/template'})
                .success(function(data){
                    element.append($compile(data)(scope));
                });
```

Comment: I also added an additional question related to this subject. Could you answer that too? Thanks!