# AngularJS: Refactor code logic within multiple directives

Tags: angularjs, refactoring

I have a bunch of directives and they share the same logic:

```
angular.module('playrApp').directive('oneofmydirective', [
  function() {
    'use strict';
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        listeners: '@'
      },
      link: function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.listeners = [].concat(($scope.listeners||'').split(' '));

        _.forEach($scope.listeners, function(listener){
          $scope.$on(listener, $scope['on'+listener]);
        });
      },
      unlink: function($scope, $element) {
        _.forEach($scope.listeners, function(listener){
          $scope.$off(listener, $scope['on'+listener]);
        });

      },
      controller: ['$scope', '$element',
        function($scope, $element) {

          $scope.onMyCustomEvent1 = function() {
            // handle event
          };
          $scope.onMyCustomEvent2 = function() {
            // handle event
          };

        }]
    }
  ]);
```

So I can use them activating listeners or not depending on the need:

```
<!-- Sometimes -->
<oneofmydirective></oneofmydirective>
<!-- And sometimes -->
<oneofmydirective listeners="MyCustomEvent1 MyCustomEvent2"></oneofmydirective>
```

How can I refactor my code to share it within every directive?

Comment: To clarify: you want to have several instances of the same directive and have all of them to react to certain events specified in the listeners attribute?

Comment: No, I have several directives `oneofmydirective`, `anotherdirective` etc. and they have specific behavior (template, controller etc.) but all have the code I have been writing upthere.

Comment: Write a factory that instantiates the shared logic functions for you. Then inject it to the directives that need the shared logic. Not sure exactly how to apply this to your example, so too lazy to provide an answer.

Since you always return a directive definition object, you have the opportunity to "mixin" behaviour to them. Composition or inheritance - not sure in your case.

Could that work for you?

Services can be injected to directives. Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569168/injecting-service-to-directive