# Access controller of directive in template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have several very similar directives which share some code. I'm looking for a way to have those directives inherit that shared code.

The approach I'm considering is having each directive's template include another directive with the shared code. Is there any way then to access that template's directive's controller?

```
app.directive('d1', function($compile) {
  return  {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'sharedCtrl', // Is anything like this possible?
    template: '<shared></shared>',
    link:function(scope,element,attr, sharedCtrl) {
        var res = sharedCtrl.getResult();
    }
  }  
});
app.directive('shared', function($compile) {
  return  {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
       var resultObject = sharedCode();
       this.getResult = function() { return resultObject; };
    }
    link:function(scope,element,attr, sharedCtrl) {

    }
  }  
});
```

Or alternatively, is there a better way to achieve the same thing?

Edit: The shared code manipulates the DOM (it injects a leaflet map, and I want to return the map js object), so I think it is best to keep DOM manipulation in a directive.

Comment: put that shared code in a factory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569168/injecting-service-to-directive

Comment: From your `shared` directive, it seems getting some data only. In this case, I think you can extract it to a `factory`.

Comment: The shared code needs to inject an element (or have it own template)  and operate on it. Is that possible from a factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently adding a function in the directive module that does the shared DOM manipulation.

```
function sharedFoo(element) {
    // DOM manipulation on element
    return result;
}

app.directive('d1', function($compile) {
  return  {
    restrict: 'E',
    link:function(scope,element,attr, sharedCtrl) {
        var res = sharedFoo();
    }
  }  
});
```

Works fine, but I'm not sure how much it follows or breaks angular conventions.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what services are for.

Turn your shared directive into a service and inject it into the first one.

```
app.directive('d1', function($compile, shared) {
  return  {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<shared></shared>',
    link:function(scope,element,attr) {
        var res = shared.getResult();
    }
  }  
});
app.factory('shared', function($compile) {
  var resultObject = sharedCode();
  return {
    getResult: function() { return resultObject; };
  }
});
```

Comment: The shared code needs to inject an element (or have it own template) and operate on it. I should be avoiding DOM manipulations from a service, no?