# Inject factory into directive's link function defined OUTSIDE of the directive's scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I saw the following question (among other similar questions) and it solves the problem of trying to inject a factory into a directive's link function:
[Injecting service to Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569168/injecting-service-to-directive/15573493#comment54799599_15573493)

The solutions I've seen keep the link function within the scope of the directive:

```
angular.module('myapp')
    .directive('myDir', function(myService){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                frame: '='
            },
            link: function postLinkFn(scope, elem, attr) {
                myService.doSomething();
            }
        };
    });
```

However, I want to be able to separate the postLinkFn outside of the .directive scope for organization, just like I can do with controllers.

Is it possible to separate this function while also injecting a service into it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.directive('myDir', function(myService){
    var deps = { myService: myService };

    return {
        ...
        // myService is available as this.myService inside postLinkFn
        link: angular.bind(deps, postLinkFn)
    };
});
```

`link` function doesn't make use of dependency injection and doesn't have lexical `this`, binding injected dependencies to `this` is a reasonable move.

Comment: Very interesting take. Thank!

Comment: Thanks it works for me, In the link function, I use this.myService and it works like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AshD You're welcome. It should be noticed that currently the right way to do this is to use $postLink controller hook instead of link function.

Comment: @estus What do you mean by "currently the right way to do this is to use $postLink "?

Comment: @Gargaroz $postLink controller method https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can put your code in a factory and then refer it globally across the app.

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('myfactory', myService, function(){
return{
var myfac;
my fac = function (myService){
  var myItem = myService.doSomething;
  return myItem;
};

};
}).
.directive('myDir', function(myService){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            frame: '='
        },
        link: myfactory.myItem;
    };
});'
```

Just a little care you need to take is binding your factory with an angular promise $q if your service deals with asynchronous calls.

Comment: Thanks Sachin. This is also a valid option but I was hoping there was something I could do that was a direct function call instead of an angular wrapped called. such as with controllers I could pass it with parameters that will be injected. Perhaps the link function does not offer this.