# Injecting service variable to Directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angularjs-injector

So I am having a bit of trouble. I have looked through all of the previous solutions from [Injecting service to Directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569168/injecting-service-to-directive), but I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I have an authServices shown below.

```
app.factory('authService', ['$http', function ($http) {

var authServiceFactory = {};

var _authentication = {
    isAuth: false,
    userName: ""
};
var _login = function (loginData) {
_authentication.isAuth = true;
_authentication.userName = loginData.userName;
}
appFactory.login = _login;
return appFactory;
}]);
```

I am injecting it via the method they had proposed.

```
    app.directive('headerNotification', ['authService', function (authService) {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'app/scripts/directives/header/header-notification/header-notification.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.authService = authService;
    }
    }
}]);
```

My html is as

```
    <li data-ng-hide="authentication.isAuth">
```

I really feel I am just doing this wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is `authentication.isAuth` in your view.

I think you miss spelled your object.

```
<li data-ng-hide="authService.isAuth">
```

Your scope object is `authService` not `authentication`, right?

**Update - Pass veraible to directive**

I am assuming that you have your auth variable in your controller.

```
$scope.myAuthService = authservice;
```

Noe you can pass this variable to your directive as an attribute.

```
<header-notification my-auth="myAuthService"> </header-notification>
```

Here `myAuthService` is a scope variable.

Change your directive to accept this variable,

```
app.directive('headerNotification', function () {
    return {
                templateUrl: 'app/scripts/directives/header/header-notification/header-notification.html',
                restrict: 'E',
                scope : {
                            myAuth : '=' // here you specify that you need to convert your attribute variable 'my-auth' to your directive's scope variable 'myAuth'
                        },
                replace: true,
                link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
                      // here you will get your auth variable
                      scope.myAuth; // this contains your auth details
                }
            }
});
```

Comment: So the object is authService with a variable _authentication.isAuth. This object should be injected to the directive which I think maybe done wrong. When I use data-ng-hide shouldn't it be the variable of the object?

Comment: @JuliusDoan, you can pass your auth variable as a parameter to this directive.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion but could you please guide me through that? Guess that was the basis of the question lol.

Comment: @JuliusDoan, check the update on my answer. Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Great works, Only thing I needed to do was add the controller to the directive.