# How to use $translate in AngularJS component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use $translate.proposedLanguage() in an AngularJS component, which allows me to initialize and configure the intl-tel-input plugin:

```
function customTel() {
return {
    restrict: 'A', // restrict as Attr
    require: 'ngModel', // require ngModel from html
    scope: {},
    link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs, $ctrl) {

        var ngModelCtrl = $ctrl; // access to ngModel with $ctrl

        var lenguaje = $translate.proposedLanguage() || $translate.use();

        if (lenguaje === "es") {
            lenguaje = "ES";
        } else if (lenguaje === "en") {
            lenguaje = "GB";
        } else if (lenguaje === "pt-pt") {
            lenguaje = "PT"
        }

        $elem.intlTelInput({
            initialCountry: lenguaje,
            preferredCountries: ["ES", "GB", "PT", "US"],
            nationalMode: true,

            utilsScript: "../../webclientes/bower_components/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js"
        });

    }
}
}

    angular
        .module('webclientesApp')
        .directive('customTel', customTel);
```

The problem is that $language is undefined, even if I inject it in the controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('webclientesApp')
        .controller('ContactaController', ContactaController);

    ContactaController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Principal', 'ContactaServiceRest', '$state', '$translate'];

    function ContactaController ($scope, Principal, ContactaServiceRest, $state, $translate) {

...
```

I have tried to inject it in the link parameter, or in the `.directive` below, but nothing has worked so far.

How can I access $translate via the component? Thanks!

Comment: change `function customTel()` to `function customTel($translate)`. View [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569168/injecting-service-to-directive) for more info

Comment: Thanks for the help, @george. Just tried that, and got this error `Error: [$injector:strictdi] customTel is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode`. Any idea why is this happening? I'm checking the answer you provided, but does not give any info on this error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your code to this it should work:

```
angular
.module('webclientesApp')
.directive('customTel', customTel);

customTel.$inject = ['$translate'];

function customTel($translate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // restrict as Attr
        require: 'ngModel', // require ngModel from html
        scope: {},
        link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs, $ctrl) {

            var ngModelCtrl = $ctrl; // access to ngModel with $ctrl

            var lenguaje = $translate.proposedLanguage() || $translate.use();

            if (lenguaje === "es") {
                lenguaje = "ES";
            } else if (lenguaje === "en") {
                lenguaje = "GB";
            } else if (lenguaje === "pt-pt") {
                lenguaje = "PT"
            }

            $elem.intlTelInput({
                initialCountry: lenguaje,
                preferredCountries: ["ES", "GB", "PT", "US"],
                nationalMode: true,

                utilsScript: "../../webclientes/bower_components/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js"
            });

        }
    }
}
```

You need to inject your dependencies in the directive function and not in the link function. Also, the reason you're getting the injection error is due to a setting you can enable in angular [see the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi), doing it this way is better anyway as it allows the files to be minified.

Comment: Spot on! :) I'm quite new in the AngularJS universe, and I still struggle to understand how it works. Thanks a lot George :)))

Comment: @wickedchild we all start somewhere, I'd recommend giving [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) a read.